# Android TileService onStartListening not called immediately?

Tags: android, android-app-quick-setting

The Android [TileService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService#onStartListening()) documentation states the following:

> When a tile should be up to date and listing will be indicated by onStartListening() and onStopListening().

Based on the lifecycle for a TileService, it's intended that you START updating your tiles state when `onStartListening()` is called.

The issue is that it doesn't seem that this callback is called immediately when the tile enters the users view. Meaning it can show outdated information for several seconds some times before the view is properly updated.

An example of this would be that a service is Connected, the tile shows it as connected. I then switch to the application, turn off the service, then open the Quick Settings view back up. It still shows the service as connected for a long time.

In theory, the moment that the tile came into view it should have updated with the new data and displayed it as not connected.

I've confirmed this is the case by simply adding a log message as the first entry in the view. When I bring the Tile into the users view, that log message isn't written to log cat for upwards of 4-5 seconds.

So, what's going on? Am I missing something?

**My Code**

```java
@Override
public void onStartListening() {
    android.util.Log.d("Test", "onStartListening called");
    updateTileDisplay();
    registerDelegate();
}
```

The `updateTileDisplay();` function is updating the title, state and icon for the Tile. Once it completes it is calling `tile.updateTile();` as it should be. Additionally, the `registerDelegate();` function is registering a delegate that will listen for internal state changes and update the tile accordingly. This delegate is later removed when `onStopListening()` is called.

I do not see that `onStartListening called` log message until upwards of 5 seconds after I have brought my tile into view. This seems not to line up with the TileService documentation.

Comment: What device is this on? It's not delayed on my Pixel 2. However, I've found a different issue where onStartListening is never called on the first swipe down of the notification shade after turning the screen on. Turns out it's because it's called when screen goes off instead...

Comment: Check the value for android.service.quicksettings.ACTIVE_TILE in the manifest. If it's set to true then the service won't be bound until it needs to handle a click event

Comment: If we take a look into the `SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/external/TileServices.java` file, we can discover the reason of such behavior. There's `recalculateBindAllowance()` function that determines how many tile services can be bound simultaneously. The threshold is set by the `setMemoryPressure()` function, which does what it says, i.e if your device suffers from memory pressure, the service bound will be postponed until your OS will free some resources to be able to allocate space for the service. To get rid of this just use an active tile, and request update on demand.

Comment: @Max_Payne awesome! The docs should probably be updated to reflect this then so that there isn't more confusion such as that which I experienced :)